# Disable ALL default shortcuts in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an easy way to disable all default shortcuts in Visual Studio Code?
From the UI, you can delete shortcuts one at a time, but due to the sheer volume of shortcuts, this would take quite some time.

Thanks

Edit 1 - When you hold delete, it continuously adds the same disable to keybindings.json. I'm guessing the fact that it updates a physical file as you interact with the UI, it requires slower user interactions.

keybindings.json after holding delete:

[image]

Comment: It's really weird behaviour you want to achieve, don't think there is something like this, haven't found any solutions. I know that for extensions you can manually disable all their shortcuts, for example, putting `"gitlens.keymap": "none",` in your `settings.json`. But really, it won't take so much time to delete all shortcus manually, just hold `Delete` button and in ~1-2 min you'll get what you want to.

Comment: @ArtemBondar unfortunately you can't just hold the Delete button, at least not on the machines I've tested. At most I could delete 1 roughly every second. Any faster and it wouldn't register the delete calls.

Answer (score 0):

> @ArtemBondar unfortunately you can't just hold the Delete button, at least not on the machines I've tested. At most I could delete 1 roughly every second. Any faster and it wouldn't register the delete calls. –

On my Windows 10 machine it's working at about 2-3 deletes/second speed.

Really don't know why you need to disable all shortcuts, just grab [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/files/3968359/keybindings.zip) `keybindings.json`.

> Edit 1 - When you hold delete, it continuously adds the same disable to keybindings.json. I'm guessing the fact that it updates a physical file as you interact with the UI, it requires slower user interactions.

It seems like to be a good reason to create a new issue at VS Codes [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).

Meanwhile, I've also found [another one](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87084) while making that `keybindings.json`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Artem, I also created an issue, but labeled mine as requested functionality. The whole delete not working is because you've deleted the shortcut key that lets you interact with the UI editor.
[Here's my issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87086)

Further, that file you've uploaded suffers from the same problem that I had, where you have a lot of duplicate entries from calling delete too quickly.

Comment: @jacobgqc Thanks, indeed I deleted shortcuts to interact with UI, then I closed my issue. Maybe duplicates aren't a big problem, so no issue is needed for this.

Comment: The gist is gone.

Comment: @haykam Yep, I wasted it, don't think that somebody will need it, but it can be restored through that issue made, so I renew the link.